# Dual boot Ubuntu & MacOS (Catalina)

Tags: dual-boot

I have a working installation on my Mac mini of MacOS (Catalina) and Ubuntu.

My problem is that I don't seem to have a 'Boot Manager.'  When performing a restart from either Ubuntu or Catalina, the system boots immediately, directly to Ubuntu.  It is only bt holding down the 'alt' (or 'option') key that the mini shows a choice of bootable volumes.

Both volumes use the disk drive icon and have labels.  One is 'EFI' and will boot Ubuntu if selected.  The other is called 'VTMini' and will boot Catalina if selected.

So, what's the problem?

The problem is that I am deploying this system 200 miles away from me and I need to control it remotely.  I'd like to simply use a shared desktop approach login to the remote mini for management.

To manage the system, I need to restart it remotely and have it boot into the 'other' operating system.  I think this can be done with a GRUB script by simply executing if ($Default='Ubuntu') then (Default='MacOS') else (Default='Ubuntu') && reboot.

But, I don't seem to have GRUB.  Anywhere.

What do I do?

Comment: If you spam the left shift key during Ubuntu boot, do you get GRUB? If so, you simply may need to do a `sudo update-grub`

Comment: What does "spam" mean in your reply?

Comment: Basically, pressing it repeatedly as fast as you can.

Comment: I installed Refund and it works as expected.

Comment: The problem remains, however.  How to remotely boot into the 'other' OS?